# If $1 \leq \|T\| \leq 2$ and $T^{-1}$ exists, is it true that $1/2 \leq \|T^{-1}\|\leq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Suppose that $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear bijective operator with operator norm 
$$1 \leq \|T\| \leq 2.$$

Since $T$ is bijective, $T^{-1}$ exists and bounded.

> Question: Is it true that $1/2 \leq \|T^{-1}\|\leq 1$?

I have a feeling that this is true but I have no idea how to prove it.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: To those who vote to close my question, may I know the reason?

Answer (score 7):

This is not true, and counterexamples can be found in $\mathbb R^2$.

Consider, for example, the matrix
$$
 A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & \frac13
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
with the euklidian norm.

Comment: At least, the assertion holds in the Banach spaces $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R$ ;)